# config['pylons.g'] AttributeError pylons

Tags: configuration, pylons

Having the following error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sa_engine'

on this line in `model/init.py`

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=False, 
bind=config['pylons.g'].sa_engine))
```

When printing config dictionary, it has 'pylons.g' key but value at this key is None.

I do not understand why it is None, config['pylons.g'] is initialized in environment.py as

`config['pylons.g'] = app_globals.Globals()`

Any ideas?

By the way, initially there no config['pylons.g'] code in the project. It was config['pylons.app_globals'] but when I tried to use it, it was not in dictionary at all.

Comment: which version of Pylons?

Comment: version 0.9.7, actually solved the problem. Forgot to initialize it in environment.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against binding the session at import time.  Do it inside init_model() instead:

```
def init_model(engine):
    meta.Session.configure(bind=engine)
```